# If both AB and AC are candidate keys for R(A,B,C), then is there any relation between B and C?

Tags: dependencies

Given the functional dependencies {AB -> C, C -> B}, then we can infer that AC is also a candidate key. I would like to know that given the functional dependencies {AB -> C, AC -> B} i.e. given that both AB and AC are candidate keys, is it possible to make either of these two inferences { B->C or C-> A }?

Comment: This is not clear. It's not clear what you are trying to ask. What does "some inference like B->C or C-> A" mean? Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS "if AB -> C, and C -> B, then we can infer that AC is also a candidate key" No, we can't.  To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must given. Because we need to know all the FDs that hold. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097)

Comment: Your "I have these FDs" doesn't make sense. "These are all the FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some FDs that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a *cover* is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097) PS Show reasoning in small steps from definitions & theorems you quote.

Answer (score 2):

If `F = {AB -> C, C -> B}` is a cover of the dependencies holding in a relation `R`, then neither `B->C` nor `C-> A` hold.

How can we say with certainty this? By computing the closure of the left parts of those FDs with respect to `F`, with a very simple algorithm discussed in almost all the books on databases. For instance, let's compute the closure of `C`, that is `C+`:

```
C+ = C
C+ = CB (because of the dependency C -> B in F)
```

no other dependency of `F` has the left part included in `CB`, so we have terminated, and since `C+` does not include `A`, we can say that `C -> A` cannot be inferred by `F`.